# Cannot generate SSPI context SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

First post here :)

I've been trying to connect to a SQL server 2016 in a pc using SSMS 2016, both EXPRESS editions.

Server shows up in Network Servers window.

I'm trying to connect with HOSTNAME\SERVERNAME and Windows authentication , I already tried a bunch of variations as :

1. HOSTNAME
2. SERVERNAME
3. tcp:HOSTNAME\SERVERNAME
4. All off the above with SQL authentication

I always get this error:

> Cannot connect to HOSTNAME\SERVERNAME
>
> Additional Information: The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server)

What I've done so far:

in host:

1. SqlBrowser is enabled.
2. Enabled Inbound TCP port 1433 and UDP port 1434 in windows firewall

in client:

1. checked if I can ping host. all good
2. checked port 1433 TCP with portqry. Listening (it identifies ms-sql-s service)
3. checked port 1434 UDP with portqry. Listening (it identifies server and instance name correctly)

I don't know what else to do.

I've read a lot of posts here and some of the proposed solutions are as described but none work.

Comment: Hi, not sure if you're still active on this site, but I'm having the same issue. The only difference is we're not using Express editions. I have found a workaround -- add `ip.ad.dr.ess hostname` to the HOSTS file on the client, and it magically works. Have you tried that? Were you able to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to remotely connect to a SQL Server 2016 instance and received that error message.  It turns out that the SQL Services (Windows) Services needed to run under a domain account to resolve this issue....